# How to use g++ -MM in a makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I can use the -MM option in g++ to generate the dependencies in a makefile rule format.

```
g++ -MM module2.cpp -I../src -I../../raven-set -I. -I../src/ext
```

outputs

```
module2.o: module2.cpp pch.h ../src/theGlobalDefines.h \
 ../../raven-set/raven_sqlite.h ../src/ext/sqlite3.h Module2.h \
 cPelexMixerComponent.h cErrorHandler.h cTimedEvent.h cPelexConfig.h \
 ../src/sgp.h ../src/cCircularVector.h ../../raven-set/cTimerBusyLoop.h \
 ../src/channelIdentification.h ../src/cPacketData.h cRxTx.h \
 cOutputTransmitter.h cDelayStats.h cMCUSB202.h cPeakerServer.h cInput.h \
 ../src/cSequenceNumber.h cRxPelexWireless.h ../../raven-set/cRunCount.h \
 cPeakFilter.h cSPO2StateMachine.h wrs_cProcessed.h ../src/log.h \
 wrs/cRaw.h wrs/cPacket.h wrs/cCalibrate.h wrs/cStream.h \
 ../src/cPelexMixerConfig.h ../src/ext/json.h wrs/cSignalProcessor_wrs.h \
 cD1ZeroCross.h ../src/cVitals.h cUI.h cTimeProfiler.h \
 ../licenser/cLicence.h cSignalProcessor.h ../src/cPeakFilterSet.h \
 ../src/cPeakFinder.h cDataRange.h cDerivativeTemplate.h \
 cDerivativePeak.h cInputRecord.h cSGPOutput.h cSignalProcessorConfig.h \
 cHeartRate.h ../src/StatusDB.h cLogger.h cKeyBoardMonitor.h \
 wrs/cStartSequence.h ../src/Configure.h ../src/HistoryDB.h \
 ../../raven-set/cRunWatch.h version.h
```

Now what do I do with this?

Is there a way for make to run the g++ -MM command and then use the generated rule?

Here is the makefile

```
#source file search paths
VPATH = wrs . ../src ../src/ext ../licenser

# compiler include search paths
INCS=-I../src -I../src/ext \
    -I. -I"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Measurement Computing\DAQ\C" \
    -I../../boost/boost1_72 

# libraries required by linker
LIBS=-lstdc++fs  -lws2_32 -lwsock32 \
    -L"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Measurement Computing\DAQ\C" \
    -lcbw64 -lIphlpapi \
    -L../../boost/boost1_72/lib \
                -lboost_thread-mgw82-mt-x64-1_72 \
            -lboost_system-mgw82-mt-x64-1_72 \
            -lboost_program_options-mgw82-mt-x64-1_72 \
            -lboost_filesystem-mgw82-mt-x64-1_72


# folder for .o files
ODIR=./obj

#  sources
_OBJ =      \
        cLicence.o  \
        sha1.o  \
        ChannelIdentification.o  \
        ChannelLabels.o  \
        Configure.o  \
        CubicSpline.o  \
        HistoryDB.o  \
        StatusDB.o  \
        cPacketData.o  \
        cPeakFilterSet.o  \
        cPeakFinder.o  \
        cPelexMixerConfig.o  \
        cVitals.o  \
        cRunWatch.o  \
        cSpline.o  \
        cTimerBusyLoop.o  \
        json.o  \
        raven_sqlite.o  \
        sqlite3.o \
        log.o  \
        cD1ZeroCross.o  \
        cDataRange.o  \
        cDelayStats.o  \
        cDerivativeTemplate.o  \
        cErrorHandler.o  \
        cHeartRate.o  \
        cInput.o  \
        cInputRecord.o  \
        cMCUSB202.o  \
        cOutputTransmitter.o  \
        cPacketAlpha.o  \
        cPacketWRS.o  \
        cPeakFilter.o  \
        cPeakFinderSustainedD1.o  \
        cPeakFinderTallPoppy.o  \
        cPeakerServer.o  \
        cPelexConfig.o  \
        cPelexMixerComponent.o  \
        cRxPelexWireless.o  \
        cRxTx.o  \
        cSGPOutput.o  \
        cSPO2StateMachine.o  \
        cSignalProcessor.o  \
        cTimeProfile.o  \
        cTimedEvent.o  \
        cUI.o  \
        module2.o  \
        sgp.o  \
        cCalibrate.o  \
        cRaw.o  \
        cSignalProcessor_wrs.o  \
        cStartSequence.o  \
        cStream.o  \
        wrs_cProcessed.o

OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(ODIR)/sqlite3.o: sqlite3.c
    gcc  -c -o $@ $<
$(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -std=c++17 -m64 -fexceptions -D_mingw_ -DMODULE2 -O2 \
         -c -o $@ $< $(INCS)

mixer: $(OBJ) 
    g++ -m64 -O2 -s -o ../bin/PelexMixer.exe $^ $(LIBS)
```

Comment: `del /q obj` and `-D_mingw_` -- First, *eww*. Second, try [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) and/or [cmake](https://cmake.org/). These new build tools were developed precisely because the `Makefile` system **is** "clumsy and tedious and inflexible".

Comment: Just to be clear.  I am asking for help using Makefile, I am not asking for recommendations for Makefile replacements.

Comment: Assuming this is `gnu make`  you might want to have a look at ["Auto-Dependency Generation"](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/#tldr).

Comment: @G.M.  Thanks.  That looks like what I need.  Except I was hoping for a gentler tutorial.

Comment: _I was hoping for a gentler tutorial._ That's your chance to make one and add a valuable (self) answer... ;-)

Comment: The shortest possible answer is, if you have GCC write that output into a file then you can use make's `include` statement to include that generated file into your makefile.  There's no need for cutting and pasting by hand or anything like that.  If you want to know how to keep those dependency files up to date automatically as the source files change, then something more complex is needed which is what the various links provided describe.  I'm not sure what you had in mind by a "gentler" tutorial but I'd be interested to read it!

Comment: side note: any reason why you don't have `_OBJ=$wildcard(*.o)` instead of hardcoded filenames? This seems quite awkward to me.

Comment: @kebs because I want only the specified source files to be compiled and linked into the executable.

Comment: @MadScientist  I do not know how to use the include statement.  I tried implementing a simple include of one dependency file but nothing seemed to happen.

Comment: You can' use `$(wildcard *.o)` of course (typo resolved) because when you start running make, and the wildcard is resolved, you haven't built any object files yet!  That's basically telling make that the list of object files it should build is the whatever object files are already built, which is never going to work.  You could, of course, use `wildcard` to find all the source files then use `patsubst` or whatever to turn them into object files.  But this is not related to the question.

Comment: Sorry, you lost me.  I copied "include $(wildcard $(DEPFILES))" from http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/#combine  What should I be using?

Comment: The use of `include` is described in the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html  Assuming you used the correct syntax then If you didn't get an error then it included the file.  However as you've described it above it won't do anything because the target in the output file is `module2.o` but the target make wants to build is `obj/module2.o` which are not the same.  You need to use the `-MT` option to change the target name if it's not the default. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: I was talking to @kebs about his comment re: _side note_

Comment: @MadScientist Am I using the wrong syntax?  I copied it from what looks to be your web page

Comment: I think you should probably open a new question, since you seem to be asking how to use the auto-generate method.  I can't tell you what might be wrong with your syntax, without seeing your syntax.  And I can't say why it doesn't work, without knowing what "doesn't work" means.  I will say that you can't just take one part of that method and use it, without the rest of the method.  That method requires that your compilation recipe also generate an appropriate dependency file as a side-effect.  "Appropriate" means, among other things, that the target in the dependency file is correct.

Comment: @MadScientist sure, you are perfectly right (about wildcard)! I use wildcard associated with patsubst in all my makefiles. The thing is I was really hurt by seiing hardcoded filenames, when make can autogenerate them (and is so powerful at it, once you understand how it works).

Comment: @MadScientist "you seem to be asking how to use the auto-generate method."  Yes, this is what I am asking.  Doesn't the title ask just that?

Comment: @MadScientist "I can't tell you what might be wrong with your syntax, without seeing your syntax. "  I have posted my syntax in the question

Comment: @MadScientist "without knowing what "doesn't work" means. "  It means that when I edit one of the header files, the source file is not recompiled.

Answer (score 0):

I need to do the following steps to generate, store and include the dependency files

This follows the hints in the [link](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/#combine) provided by @G.M  and helpful comments added to this answer

**Step 1:** define some flags requesting the generation and storage of dependencies.  Notice that I am storing both the .o and the .d files in the same folder - makes things a bit simpler

```
# flags requesting dependency generation
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(ODIR)/$*.d
```

**Step 2**  add flags to compilation rule so that they will be generated as we go along

```
$(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -std=c++17 -m64 -fexceptions -D_mingw_ -DMODULE2 -O2 \
        $(DEPFLAGS) \
         -c -o $@ $< $(INCS)
```

**Step 3** Include the dependency files

```
    # convert list of object files to list of dependency files
    DEPFILES := $(_OBJ:%.o=$(ODIR)/%.d)

    # empty rule, so make won't complain
    # about not having a rule to make the dependency file if missing
    $(DEPFILES):

    # include the dependency files 

    include $(wildcard $(DEPFILES))
```

Here is my complete makefile with the changes described above

```
#source file search paths
VPATH = wrs . ../src ../src/ext ../licenser

# compiler include search paths
INCS=-I../src -I../src/ext \
    -I. -I"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Measurement Computing\DAQ\C" \
    -I../../boost/boost1_72 

# libraries required by linker
LIBS=-lstdc++fs  -lws2_32 -lwsock32 \
    -L"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Measurement Computing\DAQ\C" \
    -lcbw64 -lIphlpapi \
    -L../../boost/boost1_72/lib \
                -lboost_thread-mgw82-mt-x64-1_72 \
            -lboost_system-mgw82-mt-x64-1_72 \
            -lboost_program_options-mgw82-mt-x64-1_72 \
            -lboost_filesystem-mgw82-mt-x64-1_72


# folder for .o files and depedency files
ODIR = ../pelexmixer/obj

# flags requesting dependency generation
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(ODIR)/$*.d

#  sources
_OBJ =      \
        cLicence.o  \
        sha1.o  \
        ChannelIdentification.o  \
        ChannelLabels.o  \
        Configure.o  \
        CubicSpline.o  \
        HistoryDB.o  \
        StatusDB.o  \
        cPacketData.o  \
        cPeakFilterSet.o  \
        cPeakFinder.o  \
        cPelexMixerConfig.o  \
        cVitals.o  \
        cRunWatch.o  \
        cSpline.o  \
        cTimerBusyLoop.o  \
        json.o  \
        raven_sqlite.o  \
        sqlite3.o \
        log.o  \
        cD1ZeroCross.o  \
        cDataRange.o  \
        cDelayStats.o  \
        cDerivativeTemplate.o  \
        cErrorHandler.o  \
        cHeartRate.o  \
        cInput.o  \
        cInputRecord.o  \
        cMCUSB202.o  \
        cOutputTransmitter.o  \
        cPacketAlpha.o  \
        cPacketWRS.o  \
        cPeakFilter.o  \
        cPeakFinderSustainedD1.o  \
        cPeakFinderTallPoppy.o  \
        cPeakerServer.o  \
        cPelexConfig.o  \
        cPelexMixerComponent.o  \
        cRxPelexWireless.o  \
        cRxTx.o  \
        cSGPOutput.o  \
        cSPO2StateMachine.o  \
        cSignalProcessor.o  \
        cTimeProfile.o  \
        cTimedEvent.o  \
        cUI.o  \
        module2.o  \
        sgp.o  \
        cCalibrate.o  \
        cRaw.o  \
        cSignalProcessor_wrs.o  \
        cStartSequence.o  \
        cStream.o  \
        wrs_cProcessed.o

OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

$(ODIR)/sqlite3.o: sqlite3.c
    gcc  -c -o $@ $<
$(ODIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -std=c++17 -m64 -fexceptions -D_mingw_ -DMODULE2 -O2 \
        $(DEPFLAGS) \
         -c -o $@ $< $(INCS)

mixer: $(OBJ) 
    g++ -m64 -O2 -s -o ../bin/PelexMixer.exe $^ $(LIBS)

DEPFILES := $(_OBJ:%.o=$(ODIR)/%.d)

$(DEPFILES):

include $(wildcard $(DEPFILES))
```

Comment: Well, this can't work.  You set `SRCS` to the value `module2`, then you replace all words that end in `.cpp` with `$(DEPDIR)/%.d` which replaces nothing because no words in `SRCS` end in `.cpp`, so `DEPFILES` is set to the value `module2`.  Then you include `$(wildcard module2)` but since (presumably) there is no file `module2`, the wildcard returns no results, and you run `include ` and don't include anything at all.

Comment: You need to set `SRCS` the list of source files for which you want to include dependency information.

Comment: The auto-generate web page says: _Also, this assumes the `SRCS` variable contains all the source files (not header files) you want to track dependencies for._

Comment: You have `_OBJ` above.  Normally people list source files in their makefile, just because it's easier to maintain, then have make convert that list into a list of object files, but if you want to keep a list of object files instead you can use `DEPFILES := $(_OBJ:%.o=$(DEPDIR)/%.d)` instead of using `SRCS`.

Comment: @MadScientist  Tried DEPFILES := $(_OBJ:%.o=$(DEPDIR)/%.d) but nothing seemed to happen

Comment: FYI, I'm pretty sure that `include` line should not start with a tab (it's not part of the recipe). Drop it down a line and remove leading spaces.

Comment: That TAB should definitely not be there.  The `include` directive is a makefile directive, that make is supposed to interpret.  Content indented with a TAB is part of a recipe, that will be passed to the shell.  `include ...` is not a valid shell command.  In your previous examples of what you had added to the makefile, you didn't have a TAB there.

Comment: The $(DEPFILES): all by itself confused me.  What does it accomplish?

Comment: It's there so make won't complain about not having a rule to make the dependency file if missing, see the [same tutorial](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/#combine). I should note that it doesn't look like you added the dependency file as a dependency to your compilation rule, which this goes with (though I'm not entirely convinced it's needed).